# How to get List<obj> from async Task<List<obj>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have this code to fetch an RSS feed async via HttpClient. How do I call this from an MVC controller and pass the data back to the view as a `List<RssFeedItem>`?

```
public class RssManager
{
    public async Task<List<RssFeedItem>> GetFeedItems(string url)
    {
        List<RssFeedItem> result = await ReadFeed(url);
        return result;
    }

    public async Task<List<RssFeedItem>> ReadFeed(string url)
    {
        List<RssFeedItem> rssFeedItems = new List<RssFeedItem>();
        string result;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        XmlTextReader rssFeed = new XmlTextReader(result.ToString());
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<RssFeedItem>));
        rssFeedItems = (List<RssFeedItem>)deserializer.Deserialize(rssFeed);
        rssFeed.Close();
        rssFeed.Dispose();

        return rssFeedItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to await it. Otherwise I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word the question right: What happens in the controller's action in calling the async method? Will it also receive a Task<List<RssFeedItem>>? How do you "unwrap" that for the view? @Jon Skeet has provided some very useful info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I call this from an MVC controller and pass the data back to the view as a `List<RssFeedItem>`?

Usually, you'd do this in *another* async method, and `await` the result. For example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Foo(...)
{
    // ...
    var list = await manager.ReadFeed(url);
    // ... maybe do something with the list
    return View(list);
}
```

In general, asynchrony is easier to handle if you don't need to switch between synchronous and asynchronous code. Here, the compiler will register the appropriate callback for the rest of your method to execute when the task returned by `ReadFeed` has completed, and it will create a `Task<ActionResult>` that will itself complete when you've provided the view. The ASP.NET infrastructre wlil handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks, @Jon Skeet. On the controller action above, why do we still need to have `Task<ActionResult>`? Is it because it's `async` and returns the `ActionResult` to the view? Do we need to have any special code in our Razor view for the async result?

Comment: @Alex: All `async` methods have to return `void` (generally only for event handlers), `Task` (if the synchronous version would return `void`) or `Task<T>` for some `T`. That's how asynchrony works - whatever calls your method won't expect it to have *finished* its work by the time it returns, so the task is a sort of token representing "the work that will eventually be done". I don't believe you need to do anything special in the view.

Answer (score 1):

By awaiting the task.  This:

```
var result = GetFeedItems(someUrl);
```

will put a `Task<List<RssFeedItem>>` in the variable `result`.  But you don't want the task, you want the result of the task.  So you would do this:

```
var result = await GetFeedItems(someUrl);
```

This will put a `List<RssFeedItem>` in the variable `result`.

Your controller methods should also be `async` in this case, following the best practice of being "async all the way down".  Essentially your code would use `awaits` to synchronously wait for the results, and consuming code (in this case the hosting web server) would use the top-level asynchronous call to free up resources while your code executes.